# Как подставить город в google autocomplete

Tags: google-maps

Как подставить город в google autocomplete?
В [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) нашел, что можно передать в `options` страну и город, для передачи страны использую `country`, как еще сюда передать город?
Пробовал использовать `locality` и указывать город, например

```
componentRestrictions: {country: 'ru', locality: 'Москва'}
```

Но так ломается поиск и не выводи не единого результата

Пример кода, где сортируется по России -

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function initialize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('address');
  var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'ru'}
  };
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  });
}
```